# В классе не видит addStuffin()

Tags: javascript, html, ооп, классы

```js
'use strict';
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var but = document.forms.burger.elements.order;
var sizeBurger = document.forms.burger.elements.sizeBurger;
var stuffingStaf = document.forms.burger.elements.stuffingStaf;
var cheese = document.forms.burger.elements.cheese;
var salad = document.forms.burger.elements.salad;
var potato = document.forms.burger.elements.potato;
var mayonez = document.forms.burger.elements.mayonez;
var spice = document.forms.burger.elements.spice;

class Hamburger {
  constructor(size, stuffing, topping) {
    this.size = size;
    this.stuffing = stuffing;
    this.topping = topping;
  }

  static get SMALLPRICE() {
    return 50
  }
  static get LARGEPRICE() {
    return 100
  }
  static get CHEESEPRICE() {
    return 10
  }
  static get SALADPRICE() {
    return 20
  }
  static get POTATOPRICE() {
    return 15
  }
  static get MAYONEZPRICE() {
    return 20
  }
  static get SPICEPRICE() {
    return 15
  }

  addStuffin() {
    var stufPrise = 0;
    if (this.stuffing == "cheese") {
      stufPrise += Hamburger.CHEESEPRICE;
    }
    if (this.stuffing == 'salad') {
      stufPrise += Hamburger.SALADPRICE;
    }
    if (this.stuffing == "potato") {
      stufPrise += Hamburger.POTATOPRICE;
    }
    return stufPrise;
  }
  calculatePrice() {
    if (this.size == "small") return Hamburger.SMALLPRICE + this.addStuffin();
    if (this.size == "large") return Hamburger.LARGEPRICE + this.addStuffin();
    else return null;
  }
}

but.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var burgerNew = new Hamburger(sizeBurger.value);
  var stafNew = new Hamburger(stuffingStaf.value);
  result.innerHTML = "Buger cost " + burgerNew.calculatePrice() + '$';
  console.log(burgerNew.calculatePrice())
  console.log(stafNew.addStuffin())
})
```

```html
<form name="burger">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select size</legend>
    <label>
          <img src="images/small.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="radio" name="sizeBurger" value="small"/>
        </label>
    <label>
          <img src="images/large.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="radio" name="sizeBurger" value="large"/>
        </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select stuffing</legend>
    <label>
          <img src="images/cheese.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="stuffingStaf" value="cheese"/>
        </label>
    <label>
          <img src="images/salad.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="stuffingStaf" value="salad"/>
        </label>
    <label>
          <img src="images/potato.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="stuffingStaf" value="potato"/>
        </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select topping</legend>
    <label>
          <img src="images/mayonez.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="mayonez" value="mayonez"/>
          </label>
    <label>
          <img src="images/spice.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="spice" value="spice"/>
          </label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" class="button" value="ORDER" name="order" />
</form>
<h3 id="result"></h3>
```

Comment: А в чём, простите, вопрос?

Comment: if (this.stuffing == "cheese") {
      stufPrise += Hamburger.CHEESEPRICE;
    } не работает

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде stuffing конструктор класса принимает вторым параметром, но вы его не передаёте.

```
  var burgerNew = new Hamburger(sizeBurger.value);
  var stafNew = new Hamburger(stuffingStaf.value);
```

замените на

```
  var burgerNew = new Hamburger(sizeBurger.value, stuffingStaf.value);
  var stafNew = new Hamburger(sizeBurger.value, stuffingStaf.value);
```

Плюс поменяте stuffing c checkbox на radio

```js
'use strict';
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var but = document.forms.burger.elements.order;
var sizeBurger = document.forms.burger.elements.sizeBurger;
var stuffingStaf = document.forms.burger.elements.stuffingStaf;
var cheese = document.forms.burger.elements.cheese;
var salad = document.forms.burger.elements.salad;
var potato = document.forms.burger.elements.potato;
var mayonez = document.forms.burger.elements.mayonez;
var spice = document.forms.burger.elements.spice;

class Hamburger {
  constructor(size, stuffing, topping) {
    this.size = size;
    this.stuffing = stuffing;
    this.topping = topping;
  }

  static get SMALLPRICE() {
    return 50
  }
  static get LARGEPRICE() {
    return 100
  }
  static get CHEESEPRICE() {
    return 10
  }
  static get SALADPRICE() {
    return 20
  }
  static get POTATOPRICE() {
    return 15
  }
  static get MAYONEZPRICE() {
    return 20
  }
  static get SPICEPRICE() {
    return 15
  }

  addStuffin() {
    var stufPrise = 0;
    if (this.stuffing == "cheese") {
      stufPrise += Hamburger.CHEESEPRICE;
    }
    if (this.stuffing == 'salad') {
      stufPrise += Hamburger.SALADPRICE;
    }
    if (this.stuffing == "potato") {
      stufPrise += Hamburger.POTATOPRICE;
    }
    return stufPrise;
  }
  calculatePrice() {
    if (this.size == "small") return Hamburger.SMALLPRICE + this.addStuffin();
    if (this.size == "large") return Hamburger.LARGEPRICE + this.addStuffin();
    else return null;
  }
}

but.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var burgerNew = new Hamburger(sizeBurger.value, stuffingStaf.value);
  var stafNew = new Hamburger(sizeBurger.value, stuffingStaf.value);
  result.innerHTML = "Buger cost " + burgerNew.calculatePrice() + '$';
  console.log(burgerNew.calculatePrice())
  console.log(stafNew.addStuffin())
})
```

```html
<form name="burger">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select size</legend>
    <label>
          <img src="images/small.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="radio" name="sizeBurger" value="small"/>
        </label>
    <label>
          <img src="images/large.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="radio" name="sizeBurger" value="large"/>
        </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select stuffing</legend>
    <label>
          <img src="images/cheese.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="radio" name="stuffingStaf" value="cheese"/>
        </label>
    <label>
          <img src="images/salad.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="radio" name="stuffingStaf" value="salad"/>
        </label>
    <label>
          <img src="images/potato.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="radio" name="stuffingStaf" value="potato"/>
        </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select topping</legend>
    <label>
          <img src="images/mayonez.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="mayonez" value="mayonez"/>
          </label>
    <label>
          <img src="images/spice.jpg" alt=""/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="spice" value="spice"/>
          </label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" class="button" value="ORDER" name="order" />
</form>
<h3 id="result"></h3>
```

Comment: А если оставить checkbox для выбора нескольких вариантов?

Comment: Тогда надо менять логику. Класс принимает только одно значение, а чекбокс подразумевает, что можно выбрать несколько значений из набора данных.

Comment: @Ofer.А как сделать чтобы checkbox видел value,у меня не получается Уже и новые вопросы задал по checkbox и radio, но мне нужно значения value в checkbox

Comment: Получить первый выбранный элемент
`
    var checkedStuff = null; 
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('stuffingStaf');
    for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
          if(inputElements[i].checked){
               checkedStuff = inputElements[i].value;
               break;
          }
    }
`
Пример взят [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11599728/1878432)